# How to use youtube-dl to download multiple videos in one txt file on mac?

Tags: youtube-dl

I got a txt file with one video url per line and there're 50 urls in total. I know youtube-dl has the feature that allows you to download multiple videos with `youtube-dl -a sample.txt`.
But I need another way to do this because I'm also using a download tool called you-get which works better on some sites. However, it doesn't support download from a txt file. Last week I find a method to convert multiple files with ffmpeg with this command `for i in *.m4a; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.mp3"; done`. I am wondering that is there any similar one line command like this one can help me read urls from the txt file and download with youtube-dl. I am using a mac btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More generally, `xargs` is specific tool for that approach.
Example:

`cat sample.txt | xargs --max-args=1 you-get`
takes each line from sample.txt, giving them as an argument to `you-get`. This ends up with 50 command lines:

```
you-get url1
you-get url2
you-get url[...]
```

and so on. This is a good tutorial, from tutorialspoint: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/xargs.htm

Comment: It perfectly solved my problem. Thank you!!

Comment: Good.... so, mark answer as accepted, it can help others :-)

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow. Already accepted! Thanks again!